# WPF - Navigation blocks application (poor performance)

Tags: wpf, performance, navigation

I have a WPF application which generates MIDI notes (a sequencer).

Besides the UI thread, there is a timer thread which triggers notes. In general, the timing is ok, but I have the following problem: Whenever I do any navigation, the application seems to "block" (i.e. the timer "stumbles" and the output stops for a short time). This happens when I e.g. open a new window or perform a navigation on a navigation window.

This also happens when I navigate to a page which is already instantiated and has been shown before.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I think the actual question is: Does anyone know of a way to make navigation faster?

Comment: Best to paste some code, especially (I think) how you're constructing and using the different threads.

Comment: I use the clock from Leslie Sanford's MIDI toolkit (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) and the regular UI thread (i.e. I don't explicitly create these threads). I tried lowering the UI thread's priority, but this did not help.

Comment: Hm, maybe post some code anyway. Looking at the CodeProject page, I'm thinking your code is executed in the same thread.

Comment: I checked this: it is executed in another thread. Which code would you like to see?

Comment: It might be interesting to see the code that's controlling the MIDI toolkit (sending it the necessary commands). The MIDI toolkit might be running in a separate thread, but if you're commands are running in your UI thread, that might explain the lag.

Comment: Well, I instantiate the clock and add an event handler to it like this which triggers notes in the end:

`midiInternalClock = new MidiInternalClock();
midiInternalClock.Tick += new EventHandler(_midiInternalClock_Tick);`

During the navigation, there is no communication to the MIDI toolkit involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but wouldn't your eventhandler (_midiInternalClock_Tick) be executed in your UI thread?

So the MidiInternalClock might be executing in another thread, but the handling of the ticks wouldn't. Like I said, not sure about this.

You might want to separate the code that works with the Midi toolkit to a separate class and then construct the clock en handle it's events in a different thread.

If that doesn't help, I'm at a loss. I guess you would then best ask your question on the CodeProject page.

Comment: The event handler is definitely executed by another thread - I checked this. But thanks a lot four your help!

Comment: If you do find the solution, it would be nice if you posted it here (you can answer your own questions). I'd like to know how it was solved. Good luck!